# Define owl carousel parameters in HTML (with class or data attribute)

Tags: html, owl-carousel

I have a page with few owl carousels. I would like to be able to set some parameters for these owl carousels in HTML code (using a class or data attribute).

Assuming I have two data attributes defined in my HTML, I have created following jQuery code:

```
$(".owl-carousel").each(function( index ) {
    var items_no = $(this).data('slides');
    var autoplay = $(this).data('autoplay');
    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        items : items_no,
        autoplay: autoplay
    });
});
```

And as you may expect it is not working. The parameters from first owl carousel are applied to all carousels. I have no idea how to make it work. Below is a fiddle with my attempt.

http://jsfiddle.net/t2gj8eg2/4/

I would be very grateful for anyone that is able to fix it for me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be:

```
$(".owl-carousel").each(function (index) {
    var items_no = $(this).data('slides');
    var autoplay = $(this).data('autoplay');
    $(this).owlCarousel({ // use $(this)
        items: items_no,
        autoplay: autoplay
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easier way to use data attributes with the Owl Carousel:

```
  var oc = $('.owl-carousel');
  var ocOptions = oc.data('carousel-options');
  var defaults = {
    loop:            true,
    nav:             false,
    autoplay:        true,
  }
  oc.owlCarousel( $.extend( defaults, ocOptions) );
```

Your HTML would look like this:

```
<div class="owl-carousel" data-carousel-options='{"autoplay":"true","autoplayTimeout":"6000","items":"2"}'> ... </div>
```

In the example above, I've defined some default options in my `defaults` variable, and then I override them with the data attributes as well as added a few more.

This is possible by using `jQuery.extend()`. Documentation can be found here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/