# Owl Carousel data options for multiple sliders on page

Tags: owl-carousel-2

I found this code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32636784/2785140 but unfortunately it does not work correctly if the page contains more than one slider.

```
var oc = $('.owl-carousel');
  var ocOptions = oc.data('carousel-options');
  var defaults = {
    loop:            true,
    nav:             false,
    autoplay:        true,
  }
  oc.owlCarousel( $.extend( defaults, ocOptions) );
```

html:

```
<div class="owl-carousel" data-carousel-options='{"autoplay":"true","autoplayTimeout":"6000","items":"2"}'> ... </div>
```

How to make it work on multiple sliders?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Init each carousel:

```
var oc = $('.owl-carousel');
oc.each(function () {
    var el = $(this);
    el.owlCarousel($.extend({
        autoplay: 2000,
        loop: true,
        items: 4,
        autowidth: true,
        nav: false,
        dots: false,
        margin: 30
    }, el.data('carousel-options')));
});
```